# shape of passed values differing from indices using init function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

**df1:**

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| b | 23 | 45 | 423 | 23 |
| c | 12 | 21 | 21 | 3 |
| s | 1221 | 12 | 21 | 12 |
| s | 21 | 34 | 5 | 6 |

```
other = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,25], 'B': [0,25], 'C': [0,25], 'D': [0,20]},
index =['a','b','c','s','s'])

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 4), indices imply (5, 4)
```

Comment: When passing a dictionary to pd.DataFrame(), since the keys of the dictionary are interpreted as column names, your DataFrame will have 2 rows and 4 columns. Passing an array of 5 elements to index keyword argument will throw error because it expects the DataFrame to have 5 rows. You can either change it to index=["a", "b"] or make each list under keys A-D have 5 elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have more indexes than rows. Instead do:

```
other = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,25], 'B': [0,25], 'C': [0,25], 'D': [0,20]}, index =['index1','index2'])
```

Because in this new dataframe you just have 2 rows (0 and 25)

Answer (score 0):

@Anabel rightly pointed out the issue.

One way to debug this would be to first create the dataframe without specifying the indices:

```
other = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': [0,25], 'B': [0,25], 'C': [0,25], 'D': [0,20]}
)
print(other)
```

The output would be:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   0   0   0   0
1  25  25  25  20
```

From here you would observe that the created df has only two indexes, i.e 0 and 1. So in order to create custom indexes, you would have to use:

```
other = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': [0,25], 'B': [0,25], 'C': [0,25], 'D': [0,20]},
    index=['a', 'b']
)
print(other)
```

And your output would be:

```
    A   B   C   D
a   0   0   0   0
b  25  25  25  20
```